# Windows 10 - Network Limited, No IP

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, ip

I have Windows 10 64-bit when I connected to my wifi, my wifi goes limited and doesn't work. When I troubleshoot my connection is saying first to
enable VMWare adapters after that it says that you have no such ip (Empty IP).

What I tried:

- `ipconfig` shows nothing
- `ipconfig /renew` and `ipconfig /release` : No operation can be performed on Bluetooth Network Connection while it has its media disconnected

I also tried:

- `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- `netsh int ip reset` and then restart

I also checked out device manager > network adapter there is no error or `!` character and all my adapters are good.

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Is this a physical machine? Where did the Bluetooth adapter come from? Has the network ever worked?

Comment: I'm interested on the answer. Windows 10 is so buggy :(

Comment: You need to add a lot more information. `Ipconfig` shows absolutely nothing? eg, you type in `Ipconfig` and it just goes directly to a new prompt?? What about `ipconfig /all`? Have you tried to release/renew only your Wi-Fi adapter (http://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html)? Are you running or have you created any virtual machines? Is this a fresh install of Windows 10 or was it an upgrade? What is the make and model of the machine? Is it by chance a laptop with the physical Wi-Fi switch turned off? As a whim, maybe try `SFC` and `DISM`?

Comment: Yea but sometimes shows that bluetooth adapter , no , that shows bluetooth adapter only + my computer info , i tried but nothing , yes Ubuntu 16 , fresh and without ANY update , sony vaio - VGN-FW378J , no its enable , what is does 2 at end ?

Comment: I have no idea that what is that bluetooth adapter ...

Comment: Oh , and i had this problem before this one again ... I searched for it , i just find nothing and I decided to reinstall my windows , and fixed but my all programs gone ;( i dont want to reinstall windows again

Comment: To solve this problem you need to learn how a network stack works. The error indicates the computer sees the network card but cant get an IP address.  This might be because there is no dhcp server running or something is blocking dhcp or arp requests.

Comment: So , ineed to found the Something ?... Can be VMWare or Kaspersky ?

Comment: I ran 'SFC' and 'DISM' but my network is limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded new build of windows 10 , and installed it with usb boot ...
And has been fixed 
I read somewhere that need to be update , microsoft has fixed it in new version

Answer (score 0):

Go to adapter settings for the network adapter in question and make sure to disable any extra drivers there. In my case having COMODO Internet Security Firewall Driver there, lead to the same problem.

Found your question while looking for a solution to my problem.

Comment: This can be a possible answer to this or other similar situations but you must consider reading [how to write a good answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on a Windows 10 laptop, turned out to be AVG filter on the adapter settings (where the TCP ipv4 settings, etc are).
Unchecked that and network started working again.